# CodedUI unable to find control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, coded-ui-tests

When I try to map the control, it gives an error that "Internet explorer is running at a lower integrity level than the current process" How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your IE is probably running in "Protected Mode", which causes this error when CodedUI interacts with the browser.

Comment: My program was in debug mode, i.e.why the error.
Thank you